# How to not fold everything when opening an org mode file?

Tags: org-mode, doom, code-folding

The default behavior of emacs is to unfold everything when opening an org mode file, I want to prevent this from happening sense my org mode files have a lot of text to be hidden.

Whenever I open an org mode file, every headline that have content inside, I want it to be hidden.

PS: I have doom emacs installed.

Comment: Does [this](https://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html) work for you?

Comment: The default used to be `overview` but it was changed to `showeverything` because new users tended to panic, thinking that they had lost most of their work when they opened the file and saw it so short. Set `org-startup-folded` to `t` in your init file to go back to `overview`.